# Docker: image won't run : No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, build.gradle

I'm working on my first, very basic Docker Image with **Spring Boot & Gradle**.
 When i run it i get following error :
`No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.`

```
02:33:59.843 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct. 
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:123)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:434)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:879)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)    
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)    
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1290)
        at be.dennisvn.demo.MoesCrudApplication.main(MoesCrudApplication.java:13)
02:33:59.875 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@d6da883, started on Thu Dec 02 02:33:59 UTC 2021
```

this is my **main class**

```
package be.dennisvn.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MoesCrudApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MoesCrudApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my **build.gradle :**

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
}

group = 'be.dennisvn'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

docker {
    name "crudformoes"
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","app.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "app.jar"])
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And this is my **Dockerfile :**

```
FROM openjdk:17.0.1
ADD MoesCrud.jar MoesCrud.jar
EXPOSE 9090
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar","MoesCrud.jar"]
```

Besides trying most suggestions on other threads, i also tried removing the `id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'` because i thought the plugin caused it. But it also doesn't solve the error.[Source of the plugin](https://github.com/ekim197711/springboot-docker-gradle) as recommended in [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7nrGLJLN5U&t=823s)

I know watching youtube tutorials isn't always the smartest way, but i find it overwhelming to find a straighforward explanation on how all this works together.I went through similar posts, but all have very specific builds,work with pom.xml files or are posted years ago.

Comment: What happens if you try to run the jar after the build directly on your system?

Comment: The command prompt returns `Error: Unable to access jarfile moescrud.jar`. I will rebuild the jar and try again !

Comment: This can be related to permission error or using an incompatible java version on you system. But it is probably not the same problem as your docker problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reminds me of a similar error I once had. The gradle build does only consider the source files you have in your project. It does not contain additional dependencies in the resulting jar file.

So this essentially means, that every dependency your project needs is not present.

To solve this you have to build an executable jar / fat jar.

## Spring boot way

You can build an executable jar with the command `./gradlew bootJar`

It is also possible to add the gradle configuration:

```
springBoot {
  exectuable = true
}
```

Note: I do not have a lot of expierence regarding this config, but the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html) give a broader overview.

## Shadow

You can also use a gradle plugin called [shadow](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/introduction/).

With it you can build an uber / fat jar which contains every dependency your app needs to run standalone.

Comment: Thank you for sharing @CrudeCode ! I just killed some babies in my project, and will try this out. 
( For what it's worth, i don't have 15 points to upvote your answer, otherwise i allready did. For the people who read this, these are very useful docs and i suggest to check them out if you are stuck as well ! )

Comment: Once you tested it, you can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem at anytime. :)

Comment: I accepted your answer as the solution. FYI, i removed all of the above, and went for the composer.jar approach. I wish i knew earlier about the composer to be honest. Once again, thanks for your invested time Crude Code ! Highly appreciate it.